# How can i add auto inreement in number using php pdo while updating to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this php to update last login and count of login
I'm it is working when i update only last login time but if i add the count of login it will show error.
I want whenever the user logout it will add + 1 in the current count 
Example last login count is 3 when logout it will add 1 and change to 4

```
<?php
session_start();  

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "thhdfhhfh";
$db_name = "users";

     try {
       $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];

     $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
     $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = :logincount + :add WHERE username = '$username'");
 $stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time); 
 $stmt->bindParam(':add', 1); 
 $stmt->execute();
   session_destroy();
   header('location:index.php');    


    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db_conn = null;


?>
```

Comment: Try to remove a ":" before `logincount`: `$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = logincount + :add WHERE username = '$username'");`

Comment: Also, you must bind `username` too, this way you do it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @ksimka please give me example of how i can do it both the binding and my question?

Comment: Like you do other binds: `$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = logincount + :add WHERE username = :username");`, `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username); `. Did removing ":" help?

Comment: Okay what about my question please give me answer to that?

Comment: Again: did you try to do what I proposed with the first comment?

Comment: No i didn't understand what you mean by remove ":" i have no double quote there please if you can just give it as answer this is the error `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /home/u64554/public_html/logout.php on line 19`

Comment: I've provided you a line of code. Just copy and paste and try.

Comment: @ksimka i just vote your reply up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = :logincount + :add WHERE username = '$username'");
$stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time); 
$stmt->bindParam(':add', 1);
```

You have 3 parameters in your query: `lastlogin`, `logincount` and `add`.
While you are only initializing `lastlogin` and `add`.

So, `logincount` is never initialized.

Since you are always increment your count by 1, try this:

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = logincount + 1 WHERE username = '$username'");
$stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time);
```

As a side note: you are kind of killing the idea of using prepared statements when you parse your username directly into the query with `username = '$username'`.

You should also use a parameter for that:

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastlogin = :lastlogin, logincount = logincount + 1 WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':lastlogin', $time);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
```